# Getting CORS issue on Angular asp.net core app on local machine (mac-os)

Tags: angular, macos, asp.net-core

Error when calling the API from Annular App: "Origin https://localhost:44419 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.".

**Question**

1. when both asp.net app and angular server running on origin (localhost) why do I
   encounter cross origin restriction ?
2. Below is the asp.net code I have and the angular proxy.conf file. I think I have enabled all the settings but still getting the error.

Angular App is running on: http://localhost:44419
Asp.Net App is running on: http://localhost:52703

```
var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(
options=>options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true);
                      })
);


app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
```

Here is the code on my angular proxy.conf.js file:

```
    const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:52703';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: You could use a Google Chrome extension to avoid cord errors ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue was in `proxy.conf.js` file. I had the http url and port mentioned there while the asp.net app was running under https port.

So after I correct the url below the issue seem to have fixed itself and I do not even need any of the `app.useCors()` and related settings listed above (the app runs just fine without that, as there is no cross origin access happening here , both asp.net and angular app running on same machine)

```
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT} :

env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:7067';
```